# Logging authentications in tomcat

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat, logging

I have a web application in tomcat 6 which requires authentication through JNDI. I need to log  in a sql db the main authentication events in this format:

> DateTime, Username, Action (logon/logoff)

The only way I've found to log auth events is to enable logging in org.apache.catalina.realm and authenticator (described [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/200811.mbox/%3C491ABEE6.40205@kippdata.de%3E)), but this kind of log is unusable for me.

Now my idea is to write a class which extends the original FormAuthenticator and to put in the authenticate() method my logging implementation.

Do you think my idea is possible to implement? Are there any other (better) options?
It seems to me that this solution is a bit obtrusive...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's possible and that is a normal and regular practice. Actually this is what inheritance is designed for, so we also use a similar logging approach in our current project, and it really works.